# Creating a photo collage image as attached using PHP from several images

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-manipulation, photos

How can i create a collage from a large number of images as per below using PHP scripts?

I am also looking at creating different sizes A0, A1, A2 sized images depending on the number of pictures used in the collage.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: When you refer to A0, A1... Are you referring to paper sizes? What do you plan to do with those collages, print them? Where do the images come from?

Comment: Anyway, you're in for a *lot* of work with this :)

Comment: yes, print them. I was hoping there are some open source components available for this?

The images will be uploaded by users or based on images that I have.

Comment: If you want to print on A2 sized paper with any decent DPI, from user uploaded images, your users better have a gooood upload speed.

Comment: A0 sizes are just when there are a lot of images. I guess most will have some 30-40 at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using Imagemagick.  There are some excellent tutorials on Mikko's blog:

http://valokuva.org/?cat=1

Take a look at the Polaroid example, here:

http://valokuva.org/?p=37

The Reflection tutorial demonstrates how to create composite images:

http://valokuva.org/?p=82

**EDIT**

Here's a few more useful links:

Image Processing (ImageMagick)
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Imagick::readImageFile
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-readimagefile.php

Imagick::rotateImage
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-rotateimage.php

Imagick::scaleImage
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-scaleimage.php

PHPro Tutorial
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Imagick.html

**And finally...**

This one is a good starting point:

Programmed Positioning of Layered Images
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#example

Comment: Thanks Mike, is there any open source component that generates images as above based on a set of input images? Or anything even close?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that you could get 'off the shelf', but perhaps somebody has already written something similar.  I don't know how you would begin searching for such a utility.  I don't think writing something in PHP would be *too* difficult.  The ImageMagick library web site has all manner of examples, including compositing examples (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/).  I'd do something like: read each image, scale it, rotate it to a random angle, place it at a random position on the output drawing. The hard part will probably be making something that fills the area properly.

Comment: Can you please update the links? Most of them are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://valokuva.org/?p=42) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Please read [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Actually this answer solved my problem .. not the accepted one

Comment: The link is dead, but still available through the Web Archive https://web.archive.org/web/20071212085625/http://valokuva.org/?p=42