# Image position coordinates calculation for creating collage

Tags: php, position, imagick

I want to create a collage in php using Imagick. I have a array of photos , I am not able to determine how to position images so that the gap between the images should be a minimum. Here is the example of what I want exactly [image: collage]
<sub>(source: [squidoocdn.com](http://i2.squidoocdn.com/resize/squidoo_images/590/draft_lens2792072module69297071photo_1258520477online-shape-collage.jpg))</sub>

Comment: already asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092583/creating-a-photo-collage-image-as-attached-using-php-from-several-images